# Serializable ViewPager in Fragment causes Android App crash when open the app from background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, serializable

I try to pass a ViewPage to Fragement in my app. But the app crashes when open app after it was killed by OS, or reopen the App from background while "Don't keep activities" is enabled at developer options.

Here is summary of the error message from Logcat:
(1) java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test3/com.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = com.test.VerticalViewPager)
(2) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name = com.test.VerticalViewPager)
(3) Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.test.VerticalViewPager; no valid constructor

After some reseraches, I found that Java class which implemented Serializable MUST has a no-arg constructor (Reference: http://burnignorance.com/java-web-development-tips/java-serialization-and-need-for-a-no-arg-constructor/).
Android Studio keeps warning me that "There is no default constructor available in 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager'" when I try to add a no-arg constructor to my ViewPager class.

I did a whole day research and still have no idea of how to solve it. Please let me know if you have any idea, thanks

Here is the Fragment class:

```
public final class FragmentTest extends Fragment {

    private static final String VERTICALVIEWPAGER = "VERTICALVIEWPAGER";

    public static FragmentTest newInstance(VerticalViewPager myVerticalViewPager) {
        FragmentTest f = new FragmentTest();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(VERTICALVIEWPAGER, myVerticalViewPager);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        // Error at this line when open the App after it was killed by OS (Or reopen the App from background while "Don't keep activities" is enabled )
        myVerticalViewPager = getArguments() != null ? (VerticalViewPager) (getArguments().getSerializable(VERTICALVIEWPAGER)) : null;
    }

}
```

Here is the ViewPager class:

```
public final class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager implements Serializable{

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // The majority of the magic happens here
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Here is full Logcat message:

> 2019-04-16 11:40:27.676 5369-5369/com.test3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main Process: com.test3, PID: 5369
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.test3/com.test.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading
>   a Serializable object (name = com.test.VerticalViewPager)     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2890)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6633)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered
>   IOException reading a Serializable object (name =
>   com.test.VerticalViewPager)   at
>   android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:3007)  at
>   android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2797)     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3115)  at
>   android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:273)
>     at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:226)  at
>   android.os.BaseBundle.getSerializable(BaseBundle.java:1199)   at
>   android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1033)   at
>   com.test.view.FragmentTest.onCreate(FragmentTest.java:79)     at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2339)     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1377)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3217)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:3166)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:181)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:319)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:84)
>     at com.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:364)    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7084)    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7075)    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2765)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2890) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1611) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6633)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)  
>   Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.test.VerticalViewPager;
>   no valid constructor  at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:147)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:757)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1778)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:374)
>     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:3005)     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2797)     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3115)      at
>   android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:273) 
>     at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:226)      at
>   android.os.BaseBundle.getSerializable(BaseBundle.java:1199)   at
>   android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1033)   at
>   com.test.view.FragmentTest.onCreate(FragmentTest.java:79)     at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2339)     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1377) 
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740) 
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809) 
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3217) 
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:3166) 
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:181) 
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:319) 
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:84) 
>     at com.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:364)    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7084)    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7075)    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215) 
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2765) 
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2890) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1611) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6633)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)

Comment: Why are you passing a `View` to a `Fragment`? That is, why isn't the `Fragment` creating its own `View`?

Comment: It is because my ViewPager instance is shared with two Fragment.

Comment: `View`s are normally not shared between `Fragment`s, any more than they are between `Activity` instances. This sounds shaky, if not outright impossible. Why doesn't each `Fragment` just create its own `VerticalViewPager`?

Comment: Thanks for inspiring me. I fixed the problem by using the ViewPager that storing at  Fragment's parent activity directly.

Comment: That sounds like the `Fragment`s are actually unnecessary, then.